# Adding vertical scrollbar to EditText programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, scrollbar

I am trying to add a vertical scrollbar to an `EditText` programmatically. If I use it in XML, it works well. Unfortunately I get a Null Pointer Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.mutate()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:21272)
```

The error is caused by the call of setScrollbarFadingEnabled.

```
inputField.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
inputField.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

The `EditText` is generated programmatically and does work well without the function call. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Is the view not updated or what might cause this error?

Answer (score 2):

**Cause:**

Turns out that the NPE is raised as `ScrollBarDrawable` is `null`; this is the `scrollbarThumbVertical` of the `EditText` scrollbar.

Enabling scrollbars programmatically with `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true)` seems to have no affect, and therefore calling `setScrollbarFadingEnabled()` raises this error.

### **Solution**

**Option 1:**

Enable the scrollbars in XML as a style, and set the style to the `EditText` using a wrapper

Create the below style:

```
<style name="scrollbar_style">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

Apply the style to the `EditText`:

```
EditText inputField = EditText(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.scrollbar_style));
```

**Option 2:**

Create a template `EditText` that has a predefined scrollbars, and inflate it instead of creating an `EditText`.

edidtext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
EditText inputField =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext, myRootLayout, false);
inputField.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
inputField.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

**Option 3:**

If you are targeting API level 29+, then you can use [`setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to set a predefined thumbnail:

```
inputField.setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(
                       ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),     
                       R.drawable.scrollview_thumb, null));
```

scrollview_thumb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#BDBBBB" />
    <size android:width="3dp" />
</shape>
```

- Option 1 is flexible for a wide range of API levels.
- Option 2 is not that elegant solution; but probably can help in other cases.
- Option 3 requires to override the default scrollbar thumbnail, and available from API level 29.